Failed to solve captcha: One or more errors occurred. (ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE)
I am attempting to create an Outlook Email Generator using 2captcha in C#, although it is not working as planned.
Everytime I attempt to solve the FunCaptcha, it returns, Failed to solve captcha: One or more errors occurred. (ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE). Here is the code that is giving that error:
FunCaptcha captcha = new FunCaptcha();
captcha.SetSiteKey("B7D8911C-5CC8-A9A3-35B0-554ACEE604DA");
captcha.SetUrl(driver.Url);
//Console.WriteLine("Solving " + driver.Url);

try
{
    solver.Solve(captcha).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Captcha solved: " + captcha.Code);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to solve captcha: " + ex.Message);
}

I have tried checking both my SiteKey and my ApiKey, but the error remains. Am I doing something wrong?
